# CSS help - how to keep my div in place with a responsive design

Tags: css

I'm playing with this design - http://codepen.io/meek/pen/MKPLLm - and trying to make a div to display an article image, title, description and upvote counter (much like reddit). I want to make it somewhat responsive, but I'm very inexperienced with this. At the moment my main problem is the fact that the upvote button and counter (div class news-vote) "falls down" when resizing the window to be narrower.

```
CSS for news-vote:

.news-vote {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 50px;
  width: 5%;
  vertical-align: top;
  float: right;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  font-size: 15pt;
}
```

CSS of surrounding elements and wrapper:

```
.wrapper {
  padding: 0px 100px 0px 100px;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 1400px;
}

.div-wrapper {
  margin-top: 40px;
  background-color: $mid;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  border: 2px $highlight solid;
}

.news {
  background-color: $lighter;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
  height: 102px;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 300px;

}

.news-img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 9%;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  min-width: 90px;
}

.news-title {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 90px;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-left: 3px;
  width: 80%;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

#title {
  color: $darker;
}

.news-img, .news-title {
  margin-top: 4px;
}
```

I have no clue how to go about ensuring there is always room for the upvote div at smaller sizes. Help very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Position:absolute on the up vote.
And position: relative on the wrapper.
Then the up vote will be positioned relative to its container.
So you can give the up vote a position like : bottom:0 
Left :0

Comment: That does it. Thanks!